# css float alternative to make li left aligned

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/o3omng/hrh1s7ss/

When I use `float : left` to li tags,
li tags go out of div whose class is na_cate.

Please Maintain li tags in center of na_cate,
and make those li tags left aligned.

Comment: [Clear the float](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hrh1s7ss/1/): `.na_cate:after { content: ""; display: block; clear: both; }`

Comment: @HashemQolami Did you mean : `.na cate ul li { float : left ; display : block ; clear : both ; }` like this?

Comment: @HashemQolami I Checked your fiddle, but the li tags must maintain the center.

Comment: So why are you using CSS float? [display the list items as inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/hrh1s7ss/3/) instead, and add `text-align: center` to their parent.

Comment: @HashemQolami You mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/o3omng/hrh1s7ss/4/), and This is what I exactly want. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set `text-align: center;` to `div.na_cate ul` and `display: inline-block;` to `div.na_cate ul li`

### TRY - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cLp2k0sg/1/)

You could do this:

```
.na_cate ul {
    list-style: none ;
    text-align: center;
}
.na_cate ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float of your container.

```
.na_cate li {
   float:left;
   margin-left:20px;
}

.na_cate ul { 
   list-style:none;
   overflow:hidden;  /* clearfix */
}
```

Alternatively, here is [another clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) that doesn't use overflow but pseudo elements instead.